# Firefox tries to open application/octet-stream with gedit

Tags: linux, firefox, fedora, gnome, mime-types

I'm using Firefox 41.0.1 on Fedora 22.

I noticed this behaviour when I was trying to open a PNG image link on a GitLab site. The server replies with `"Content-Disposition:"inline; filename="logo.png"` and `Content-Type:"application/octet-stream"`.

**I want it to either display the image on the browser, or offer me to open it on the system default image viewer.** I know it is possible, at least in Windows. See the GIF below kindly provided by @JourneymanGeek:

[image]

I made some tests using [this tool](http://entropymine.com/jason/testbed/mime/) and, apparently, when I click a link and the response headers contains the `application/octet-stream` mime type, Firefox offers me to open the file using gedit, stating it's the default application.

[image]

- If I download the file (in this case, a PNG image) and double-click on it, it opens on Eye of Gnome.
- `xdg-open` also opens it in Eye of Gnome.
- `application/octet-stream` isn't present on `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`
- `$ grep "gedit" /usr/share/applications/defaults.list` returns only `text/plain=org.gnome.gedit.desktop`
- I have removed the `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/mimeTypes.rdf` file and the issue persits.
- I have also removed the `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file and the issue still persists.
- I have restarted Firefox and logged out of my Gnome profile as well.

Here's the Firefox file association screen:

[image]

So, again, my question is: is it possible to have Firefox either **display the file on the browser** (if it is a file it's able of rendering), or **offering the correct application** able of rendering it (if there's one on the system)?

Or does the server declaring the incorrect mime-type renders it all impossible?

Also, **why is it thinking `gedit` is the default `octet-stream` handler**? Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have also removed the `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file and the issue still persists.

There is likely another `mimeapps.list` elsewhere on the system. You can go through the list [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications), or search through your system with one of the following commands:

```
locate mimeapps.list
```

or

```
find / -name 'mimeapps.list'
```

Check for any `application/octet-stream` entries in those, and either comment them out or remove them.

Comment: For me it was `~/.config/mimeapps.list` that contained `application/octet-stream=org.gnome.gedit.desktop`.

Comment: (This answer was posted following [some chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24823898#24823898).)

Comment: Thanks man. Removing the line fixed this immediately. Was struggling with that for months now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems that Firefox will not fix this [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67940) but I fixed it in my way removing the `application/octet-stream=org.gnome.gedit.desktop` from my `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and using the add-on [OpenDownload²](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/opendownload-10902/?src=userprofile) to provide me the `Run` option.

If the extension of the file being downloaded is correctly configured in the `mimeapps.list`, firefox will open **(run)** it like a charm.

Comment: By the way I'm using Firefox 41.0.2 on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

@Bob answered part 2 of the question: how to control which app opens the file.

The answer to part 1 is: Firefox downloads all files of type application/octet-stream **by design**. According to the HTTP standard, [a compliant browser MUST NOT second-guess the server if a content-type is specified](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1303555#p6725425). Since octet-stream files contain arbitrary data, the browser should download them.

Most browsers ignore the standard in favor of user friendliness. Firefox does not. As stated in @Geyslan's answer, you would need to use a 3rd party extension to circumvent this design choice.